# calculate coefficient of determination (R2) and root mean square error (RMSE) for non linear curve fitting in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statsmodels

How to calculate coefficient of determination (R2) and root mean square error (RMSE) for non linear curve fitting in python. Following code does until curve fitting. Then how to calculate R2 and RMSE?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

x = np.linspace(0,4,50)
y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
yn = y + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, yn)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, yn, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: According to this [post](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2962) from one of the statsmodels developers,  `std_err` from `scipy.stats.linregress` is actually the error in the slope coefficient.  This value is not the same as RMSE, which is the (average of the squared residuals)^0.5, a different value that actually changes with the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Nope, the scipy document says that SE is Standard error of the estimate. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress

Comment: In the link I provided, the author of the scipy doc you gave addresses this definition. His posts confirm scipy's SE is the error in the slope.

Comment: from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
print "Mean Squared Error: ", np.mean((y-func(x, *popt))**2)

ss_res = np.dot((yn - func(x, *popt)),(yn - func(x, *popt)))
ymean = np.mean(yn)
ss_tot = np.dot((yn-ymean),(yn-ymean))
print "Mean R :",  1-ss_res/ss_tot
```

This is taking the definitions directly, as for example in the wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions

Comment: Quick correction: according to the wikipedia page you linked, the value you give for "Mean R" is actually R^2.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Böschen, not `y` but `yn` here:

```
np.mean((y-func(x, *popt))**2)
```

And read this about root-mean-square error (RMSE): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

```
residuals = yn - func(x,*popt)
print "RMSE",(scipy.sum(residuals**2)/(residuals.size-2))**0.5
```

Now it calculates as Excel 2003 Analysis ToolPak.