# R²-value calculation for non linear least squares curve fittingin Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have written a code in which I would like to calculate the R²-value for a nonlinear fit by a given Force-Depth relation.

The Code I am using for the given x- and y- data is:

> ```
>    ydata=npy.array(N)
>    xdata=npy.array(depth)
>
>    #Exponential Law
>
>    def func1 (x,Bo,k):
>        return Bo*npy.exp(x*k)
>    popt, pcov, infodict, mesg, ier = curve_fit(func1, xdata, ydata,p0=(1.0,0.2),full_output=True)        
>    Bo=popt[0]
>    k=popt[1]
>
>    SSR1=sum((func1(ydata,Bo,k)-xdata.mean())**2)
>    SST1=sum((xdata-func1(ydata,Bo,k))**2)
>    rsquared1=SSR1/SST1
> ```

for a exponentail Law and:

> ```
>    #Power Law
>
>    def func2(a,Bp,z):
>        return Bp*a**z
>    popt2, pcov2=curve_fit(func2,xdata,ydata,p0=(1,0.2),bounds=([-npy.inf,0],npy.inf))
>    
>    Bp=popt2[0]
>    z=popt2[1]
>
>    residuals2 = func2(ydata,Bp,z)-xdata.mean()
>    fres2=sum(residuals2**2)
>    ss_tot2=sum((xdata-func2(ydata,Bp,z))**2)
>    rsquared2=(fres2/ss_tot2)
> ```

for the Power Law.
According to rsquared =SSR/SST, this should give me values between 0 and 1. Unfortunately I get for some values a rsquared which is slightly larger than 1.

An example for the values where the r-squared is larger than 1 is:

xdata(Depth):
[  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.
30.  36.  38.  40.  42.  44.  46.  48.  50.  52.  54.  56.  58.]

ydata(Force):
[   0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     4.4    8.    20.    36.
30.8   12.4    5.8    3.2    4.     3.8   54.6   15.6   37.2   39.6
76.8   81.2  111.   142.4   76.8  107.2  151.8  131.4]

I am thankful for every help

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

> Values of R2 outside the range 0 to 1 can occur where it is used to measure the agreement between observed and modeled values and where the "modeled" values are not obtained by linear regression and depending on which formulation of R2 is used.

I think in your case you may simply have `x` and `y` the wrong way around... Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115272/calculate-coefficient-of-determination-r2-and-root-mean-square-error-rmse-fo?rq=1) answer with your data, I do,

```
import numpy as npy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#Exponential Law
def func1(x,Bo,k):
   return Bo*npy.exp(x*k)

#Power Law
def func2(a, Bp, z):
   return Bp*npy.power(a, z)


def get_rsq(f, y, popt):

    ss_res = npy.dot((y - func1(x, *popt)),(y - func1(x, *popt)))
    ymean = npy.mean(y)
    ss_tot = npy.dot((y-ymean),(y-ymean))
    return 1-ss_res/ss_tot



x = npy.array([0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10., 12., 14., 16., 18., 20., 22., 24., 26., 28., 30., 36., 38., 40., 42., 44., 46., 48., 50., 52., 54., 56., 58.])
y = npy.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 4.4, 8., 20., 36., 30.8, 12.4, 5.8, 3.2, 4., 3.8, 54.6, 15.6, 37.2, 39.6, 76.8, 81.2, 111., 142.4, 76.8, 107.2, 151.8, 131.4])


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func1, x, y, p0=(1.0,0.2))
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(func2, x, y,p0=[0.0008,3.0],bounds=([-npy.inf,0],npy.inf))


plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Data")
plt.plot(x, func1(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Exponential Law")
plt.plot(x, func2(x, *popt), 'b-', label="Power Law")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print "Mean R Exponential:",  get_rsq(func1, y, popt)
print "Mean R Power:",  get_rsq(func2, y, popt2)
```

and the exp fit comes out as,

```
Mean R : 0.856908603298
```

The power law fit fails sensationally (`-4.64462440385e+140`), which I think is expected based on similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903506/scipy-curve-fit-fails-power-law)), and I guess why you added bounds. My `scipy` is pre 0.17 so can't test but maybe you'll have more luck here too.